# Image source is different in html between my browser and get request

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I suspect this has happened due to my misunderstanding of how either lxml or html works and I'd appreciate if someone could fill in this blank in my knowledge.

My code is:

```
url = "https://prnt.sc/ca0000"
response = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'})

# Navigate to the correct img src.
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/img/@src'

imageURL = tree.xpath(xpath)[0]

print(imageURL)
```

I expect when I do this to get a result such as:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...((THIS IS REALLY LONG))...Jggg==

Which if I understand correctly is where the image is stored locally on my computer.

However when I run the code I get:

> "https://prnt.sc/ca0000"

Why are these different?

Comment: server may send different HTML to different browser and/or devices (desktop, notebook, tablet, phone). It may uses header `User-Agent` to recognize browser and you may have to set correct value in requests - `Chrome` may not be enough. It can be also other problem - many modern pages use JavaScript to add content (and to detect bots/scripts) but requests can't run JavaScript.

Comment: in HTML I see two `img` with different `scr` - one of them has link to image and other has `https://prnt.sc/ca0000`. You could use wrong `xpath` - better use `id` and `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that this page uses `javaScript` to put `data:image/png;base64 ...` in place of `https://prnt.sc/ca0000` but `requests` can't use `JavaScript`.

But there are two `img` with different `scr` - first has standard URL to image (`https:///....`) and other has fake `https://prnt.sc/ca0000`

So this xpath works for me even without `JavaScript`

```
xpath = '//img[@id="screenshot-image"]/@src'
```

---

This code get correct url and download image.

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "https://prnt.sc/ca0000"

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'})

tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

image_url = tree.xpath('//img[@id="screenshot-image"]/@src')[0]

print(image_url)

# -- download ---

response = requests.get(image_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'})

with open('image.png', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(response.content)
```

Result

```
https://image.prntscr.com/image/797501c08d0a46ae93ff3a477b4f771c.png
```

---